# Linux CPU and memory percentages

Tags: xfce

Is there a command which outputs *just* current CPU usage percentage and current memory usage percentage? As a single number, so no tables or formatted output.

The reason I'm asking. For my panel in XFCE I'd like to see something like this:

`CPU 34% | MEM 56%`

I haven't found a plugin which does that, so I aim to use the Generic Monitor plugin and give it a command which it should print and let it update every 1 sec.

Comment: "No tables or formatted output" is a non-Linux attitude, isn't it ? Grep, grep, grep...

Comment: A command using grep or other piped commands is of course also fine. But I can't figure out (or find online) how to build one so that 1 value comes out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following snippet somewhere in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CPU=$(lscpu | grep '\(CPU\|max\) MHz:' | xargs echo | awk '{printf "%3.0f\n", $3*100/$7}')
MEM=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%3.0f\n", $3*100/$2}')
echo CPU $CPU% \| MEM $MEM%
```

And call it from genmon as `bash /path/to/this/script.sh`.